# SQLite query sometimes not fetching all data

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I am working on Ionic 1 project. I have applied a query to get data corresponding to the project ID but it is not returning all data sometimes. Sometimes the length is 1 or 2 or 6. It should return 6 always. What can be the issue?

```
self.getTeamMembersByProjectID = function(projectID) {
        var parameters = [projectID];
        return DBA.query("SELECT * FROM TeamMembers WHERE projectID = (?) ORDER BY displayName", parameters)
            .then(function(result) {
                return DBA.getAll(result);
            });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to loop through the result first then push it to an array 
I had a smilier issue before and this what I have done

```
 $scope.ShowAllData = function() {       /* SELECT COMMAND */       
                $scope.images = [];      
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"SELECT * FROM imageTable ORDER BY id DESC").then(   function(res) {          
                    if (res.rows.length > 0) {            
                        for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) { 
                            $scope.images.push({                
                                id: res.rows.item(i).id,
                                image: res.rows.item(i).images


                            });            
                        }          
                    }        
                },         function(error) {          
                    alert(error);        
                }      );

                return $scope.images;     
            }
```

Comment: in my case, result sometimes does not contain all data, loop wont work in that case. it will loop through only those data which is fetched

Comment: check your SELECT method

Comment: query is correct. its just a simple select query with where clause